# Imprimir lista simplesmente encadeada ao contrário em C

Tags: c

Tenho uma lista simplesmente encadeada onde cada nó tem um valor, sendo eles, respectivamente, 1, 2, 3, 4 e 5. Quero imprimir os valores da lista apenas por questões estéticas como 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 sem criar outra lista. De que forma posso fazer isso? Estou sem ideias.

Comment: Basta chamar a função de modo recursivo. Dê uma olhada nessa função https://pastebin.com/HPcTFAzv.

Comment: E uma dica pra você que é usuário novo, faça perguntas mais detalhadas, coloque por exemplo como o seu tipo lista está declarado e outras informações importantes.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado Lucas pelo exemplo e pela dica.

Comment: mostre o que você já fez até agora, o que não funcionou, etc